# Generate tiles from large photos (iOs PhotoScroller)

Tags: ios, photo, tiles

I'm studdying the **WWDC session #104 for mastering UIScrollViews**. I need to create a script or find a tool or write a script to generate the tiles needed for the CATiledLayer from some large jpg photo.

1000 500 and 250 scale factors are needed and the generated tiles need to respect a naming pattern like this:

```
name_scale_col_row.jpg
```

Any suggestion for a tool or script that I could use for this or do I need to write one?

**EDIT**: I'm working on my own little bash script. This is what I did until now:

```
#!/bin/sh

file_list=`ls | grep png` 

for i in 25 50 100; do 
    for file in $file_list; do
        convert $file -scale ${i}%x${i}% -crop 256x256  \
        -set filename:tile "%[fx:page.x/256]_%[fx:page.y/256]" \
        +repage +adjoin "${file%.*}_${i}0_%[filename:tile].${file#*.}"
    done
done
```

Of cours it's far from being a real tool but it works and respect the Apple photoscroller example naming convention for tiles. Any suggestion, improvement appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script will automatically generate all the tiles you need at all the different resolutions:

http://www.mikelin.ca/blog/2010/06/iphone-splitting-image-into-tiles-for-faster-loading-with-imagemagick/

A small heads up: that script will name everything with 100, 50, etc. scale factors rather than 1000, 500, etc. you can adjust for this by changing 1000 to 100 in the tileForScale: method in TilingView.m in the PhotoScroller example.

Comment: Useful, thanks- please add support for stripping periods in the filename for cases where s=12.5

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a tool to generate tiles and found out Photoshop (CS3 or later) includes an option to create JPEG tiles for a tool called Zoomify. From the menu choose File > Export > Zoomify... and in 'Browser Options' fill in the tileSize of 256 x 256 pixels.

After clicking [OK] a folder TileGroup0 will be created with the 256 pixel tiles.
The files are named: `zoomlevel-column-row.jpg`, whereas Photoscroller's example files are named `filename_scale_column_row.png` (the `0-0-0.jpg` file can be discarded). So rename the jpg-files accordingly (`1- = 125_, 2- = 250_, 3- = 500_`, etc.) or just fix `tileName` in `tileForScale:row:col:` (TilingView.m) to load the correct jpg file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using two tools--[Tilen](http://www.nasolab.com/tilen/index.html) for chopping up the image, which unfortunately starts tile numbering at 1, and then [Better Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/) for adjusting the tile numbering and adding appropriate prefixes and suffixes to the names.  Together they do a great job.

Comment: Tilen also has the problem in that even the end tiles of an image that is not a multiple size of the tile size are created at the tile size and not the 'leftover' size. This is different than image magick.